# Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.SimpleMessage]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat

I'm trying to run Spring Boot + Hibernate + REST application from external Tomcat 9.0.0 server. When running locally from Intellij (which also uses embedded Tomcat server) everything works fine, but on external Tomcat initially it looks fine, the server is starting up, but after a moment the application stops working

```
[Hibernate Connection Pool Validation Thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.SimpleMessage]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apache.logging.log4j.message.SimpleMessage]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1289)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1277)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.message.AbstractMessageFactory.newMessage(AbstractMessageFactory.java:59)
        at org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger.doLog(Log4j2Logger.java:55)
        at org.jboss.logging.Logger.debug(Logger.java:552)
        at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.debug(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:284)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections.validate(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:332)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Any ideas what may cause this issue?